# Unspecified warning when using firebase orderByChild in react-native with redux

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

I am getting a mystery yellow-box error when adding an orderByChild firebase filter in my react-native project, even though the app is reading and filtering the data fine.

Everything works fine if I remove the orderByChild.

Code giving warning:

```
export const peopleFetchAll = ({ name }) => {
console.log(`${name}`);

return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.database().ref(`/people`).orderByChild("name").equalTo("Paul")
    .once('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({ type:PEOPLE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload:snapshot.val() });
    });
  };
};
```

Good code:

```
export const peopleFetchAll = ({ name }) => {
console.log(`${name}`);

return (dispatch) => {
  firebase.database().ref(`/people`)
    .once('value', snapshot => {
        dispatch({ type:PEOPLE_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload:snapshot.val() });
    });
  };
};
```

The error I see in Expo is:

```
▼[2019-02-02T21:25:30.973Z]  @firebase/database:
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:80:15 in warn
- node_modules\expo\src\Expo.js:25:41 in warn
- node_modules\@firebase\logger\dist\index.cjs.js:66:31 in defaultLogHandler
- node_modules\@firebase\logger\dist\index.cjs.js:152:31 in warn
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:345:19 in warn
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:11818:21 in warnOnListenWarnings_
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:11788:55 in <unknown>
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:12052:27 in onDataMessage_
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:11337:24 in onDataMessage_
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:11331:32 in onPrimaryMessageReceived_
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:11232:52 in <unknown>
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:10837:27 in appendFrame_
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:10887:34 in handleIncomingFrame
- node_modules\@firebase\database\dist\index.cjs.js:10784:38 in onmessage
- node_modules\event-target-shim\lib\event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\WebSocket\WebSocket.js:239:27 in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:180:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:351:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:116:26 in <unknown>
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:6 in __guardSafe
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:115:17 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Again, everything works fine even though I get the warning.  I just need to get rid of the warning and I can't seem to decipher this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define an index on `name` under `/people` as shown here: firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data?

If not, that is probably the reason for the warning, although I don't understand why it would not be showing the actual warning message.